# A Trivial Pursuit #05 (Science and Nature 1/4): Animal Songs

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, music, animals

<sub>This is part 5 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

> ♩
> ♩♩♩♩♩ G
> E G S T H E M A M ♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩
> H ♩♩
> D A ♩
> R ♩♩
> B F T B O M ♩♩
> ♩♩♩♩♩♩♩♩ W
> I A T ♩♩♩♩♩
> ♩♩♩♩♩♩

*Turdus merula*
*Cyanocitta cristata*
*Canis lupus familiaris*
*Milvus milvus*
*Cercopithecidae*
*Octopoda vulgaris*
*Sus domesticus*
*Equus ferus caballus*
*Procyon lotor*
*Odobenus rosmarus*

**The answer is a relevant 10-letter word.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> **Sphaerites** (which is a genus of beetles)

Because all of these is an animal contained in a title of

> a song by **The Beatles**!

> [image]

The note symbol corresponds to the

> n:th letter of the corresponding scientific name.

Comment: Ahhh, a minute before my submission of the same solution. Nicely done nonetheless.

Comment: That last step was nicely spotted. I overthought there

Comment: I'm going to have to start watching for these; they're fun but there's genuine race element.

Comment: CatProgrammer Thanks. @oAlt Yeah, I couldn't makes sense of it from the beginning either but then realized they must correspond to the scientific names (given the number of notes which didn't match some of the word of the animals).

Comment: This is correct, indeed :) And yes, I chose the indices deliberately so that some would be out of range for the wrong set of options, to prompt the solver that what they had found would be worth googling to check it was real!